# Is the fact that elementary particles have uncorrelated masses a sign that they are not fundamental?

Tags: mass, standard-model, higgs, quarks, elementary-particles

The masses of elementary particles in the Standard Model seem uncorrelated.

They range from $0$ to $173.1\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{GeV}}{c^2}\right)$ without a functional dependence.

In the Standard Model the masses are explained by the coupling of the particles to the Higgs field. The coupling strengths though have no (known) functional dependence either. They are put in by hand.

But can't it be that these different masses are a sign that the particles are composite? In which case the more elementary particles could actually have mass zero (so no interdependence is needed) and the mass of the observed particles emerges from an interaction of these massless particles? Which has to be big enough to keep them together, obviously.

What if some functional dependence was discovered? Would this invalidate the Higgs mechanism (not the boson, obviously)?

Comment: There's no *known* functional dependence of the masses / Yukawa couplings on something deeper, but that doesn't mean there isn't.

Comment: @G.Smith My question was edited. I'll edit again

Answer (score 2):

If anything it's the other way round.   If there were some relation between particle masses, that would be a very big hint that there was some more fundamental theory behind them.

In the same way that the energies of the excited states in hydrogen, as measured by the spectroscopists, being proportional to $-1/n^2$ with $n=1,2,3...$ turns out to be due to the Bohr model (and later the Schroedinger equation).

Comment: But the potential in hydrogen is known, hence the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ relation. Maybe the potential due to the eventual sub-particles grows stronger with increasing distance, In that case, what would be the relationship? The masses of the higher generation particles do somehow agree with this (**if** there was such a potential).

Comment: For example, the mass of the -2/3 quarks grows slower than that of the -1/3 quarks.  If the subs have -1/3 this is understandable (the potential energy due to the electric potential decreases while the other (unknown) increases.

Answer (score 1):

It does not necessarily mean that they are not fundamental. But the large range of particle masses suggests that there may be some complicated mechanism that gives them their masses. Although different mechanisms have been proposed, apart from the Yukawa couplings, there is no understanding of the diversity in these masses as far I know.

Comment: What do you mean by your first sentence? Are you implying that it's known that, say, the leptons are not fundamental?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo.